# External link is not working in Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I have two `docker-compose.yml` files. In the first one, I run a mongodb instance:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

In the second one, I run my web app and I want to link it with mongodb container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
    external_links:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

But, when I run my webapp, I get a connection error. I'm connecting to this URI:

```
const DB_URI = 'mongodb://mongodb:27017/mydb';
```

but I get `MongoNetworkError`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it a requirement that they be in different docker compose files?

Comment: Can you `ping mongodb` from inside your webapp container?

Comment: I found the error. It's because they ar in different docker networks. @Rickkwa it's not a requirement but I need mongodb to be up and running before start webapp. How can achieve that with both services in the same docker-compose file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Hosts were not accessible because they were in different networks. Creating a network (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and running both services in that network solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use those two services in the same docker-compose file and replace **`external_links`** with **`links`**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

**How could I ensure mongodb is up and running before webapp is started?**
AFAIK, the **`links`** will take care of the the situation.
**or**
You could use [**`depends_on`**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Comment: Thank you. How could I ensure mongodb is up and running before webapp is started?

Comment: *`links`* also will  take care of that too